# How to connect list of places with Google Map Points

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

They are 2 separate entities atm:

https://jsfiddle.net/31b2tbpu/13/

I wish to link them so clicking on a list item makes the box appear on the respective map item, and clicking on the map item changes the colour etc. of the list item.

Do I need each anchor to call a function that alters:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
})(marker, i));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. keep an array of markers so you can access them by index

   var gmarkers = [];
2. push the markers onto that array as they are instantiated.
3. add code to `click` on the appropriate marker when the `li` element is clicked:

```
$('#list li').each(function(i, e) {
  $(e).click(function(i) {
    return function(e) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], 'click');
    }
  }(i));
});
```

*Note that this code assumes the locations array and the list items are in the same order.  You could use the name or ids instead of that assumption.*

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/31b2tbpu/25/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// Locations: [title, lat, long, number]
var locations = [
  ['Bar Termini', 51.51367, -0.12981, 1],
  ['French House', 51.51272, -0.13170, 2],
  ['Mark\'s Bar', 51.51133, -0.13563, 3],
  ['Hakkasan (bar)', 51.51017, -0.14474, 4],
  ['Bar Américain at Brasserie Zédel', 51.51017, -0.14474, 5],
  ['Experimental Cocktail Club', 51.51193, -0.13103, 6],
  ['Milk & Honey', 51.51377, -0.13653, 7],
  ['Blind Pig', 51.51379, -0.13668, 8],
  ['Opium', 51.51176, -0.13145, 9]
];
var gmarkers = [];
// Map Settings
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
  zoom: 16,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.51367, -0.12981),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    label: String(locations[i][3])
  });
  gmarkers.push(marker);
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
$('#list li').each(function(i, e) {
  $(e).click(function(i) {
    return function(e) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], 'click');
    }
  }(i));
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="page" id="map_result">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Multiple Marker</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" style="padding:0;">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="list">
      <ol>
        <li>
          <a>Bar Termini</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>French House</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Mark's Bar</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Hakkasan (bar)</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Bar Americain at Brasserie Zedel</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Experimental Cocktail Club</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Milk &amp; Honey</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Blind Pig</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Opium</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```