# Adding additional functionality to Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Following on from:

[How to connect list of places with Google Map Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182728/how-to-connect-list-of-places-with-google-map-points/35183997#35183997)

I am adding functionality to change the colour of the active pin either by clicking the pin itself or the respective li:

https://jsfiddle.net/31b2tbpu/30/

I added this in (in similar fashion to the infoWindow object but with the marker object instead) but it doesn't appear to work?

```
marker.icon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|34BA46");
```

Comment: it's better to post your code HERE rather than on an external site ... having said that, the code in that jsfiddle has nothing that even attempts to change the colour of a pin

Comment: Yes it does! I posted it here.

Comment: infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      marker.icon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|34BA46");

Comment: that `marker.icon` code you posted here **is not in the fiddle**

Comment: Too many different versions! I have added the correct one now.

Comment: so, you see the error which says `TypeError: marker.icon is not a function
` ?

Comment: use `marker.setIcon(...`

Comment: Okay thanks. Is there some kind of documentation that specifies all functions for certain objects? Google Maps API guide can be like a haystack!

Comment: and they usually remove the needle when you aren't looking :p ... I **hate** googles documentation in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no function called icon.
use this

```
marker.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|34BA46");
```

Comment: Thanks both of you. I am trying to work out a way of changing it back when another is selected?

Comment: before the line paste this code
for (j = 0; j < gmarkers.length; j++) {
       gmarkers[j].setIcon("http://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-poi.png");
      }