# How to change Google Map Center consecutively on random markers by clicking one button

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, markers

I am quite new to programming. I am trying to put four random markers on Google Maps API v3 and add a classic button on the web page that will center the map one by one on these markers. If the center is on the third marker then the next click should center the map on the first marker etc.
I can't use jquery or any other library except classic javascript and html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Code from [Previous SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35183997/3898339) and adding `map.panTo(marker.getPosition());` to the existing code will center the map based on marker list is clicked or  button clicked.

See full screen for better result

```js
// Locations: [title, lat, long, number]
var locations = [
  ['Bar Termini', 51.51367, -0.12981, 1],
  ['French House', 51.51272, -0.13170, 2],
  ['Mark\'s Bar', 51.51133, -0.13563, 3],
  ['Hakkasan (bar)', 51.51017, -0.14474, 4],
  ['Bar Américain at Brasserie Zédel', 51.51027, -0.14474, 5],
  ['Experimental Cocktail Club', 51.51193, -0.13103, 6],
  ['Milk & Honey', 51.51377, -0.13653, 7],
  ['Blind Pig', 51.51379, -0.13668, 8],
  ['Opium', 51.51176, -0.13145, 9]
];
var gmarkers = [];
// Map Settings
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
  zoom: 16,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.51367, -0.12981),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    label: String(locations[i][3])
  });
  gmarkers.push(marker);
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

function centerMap(obj) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[obj], 'click');
}

function pickRandom() {
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 0;
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[rnd], 'click');
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="map_result">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Multiple Marker</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" style="padding:0;">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <button onclick="pickRandom()">Random Select</button>
    <div id="list">

      <ol>Click on Link Below
        <li onclick="centerMap(0)">
          <a>Bar Termini</a>
        </li>
        <li onclick="centerMap(1)">
          <a>French House</a>
        </li>
        <li onclick="centerMap(2)">
          <a>Mark's Bar</a>
        </li>
        <li onclick="centerMap(3)">
          <a>Hakkasan (bar)</a>
        </li>
        <li onclick="centerMap(4)">
          <a>Bar Americain at Brasserie Zedel</a>
        </li>
        <li onclick="centerMap(5)">
          <a>Experimental Cocktail Club</a>
        </li>
        <li onclick="centerMap(6)">
          <a>Milk &amp; Honey</a>
        </li>
        <li onclick="centerMap(7)">
          <a>Blind Pig</a>
        </li>
        <li onclick="centerMap(8)">
          <a>Opium</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your comment that is HIGHLY appreciated my friend. Actually all I have asked was to click the button and go from one point to the next something like graph navigation to nodes (1->2->3->4). Perhaps I wasn't accurate with my description. But now I have all I need to try it on my own based on your code.

Comment: ok you want like 1->2->3->4 . First you try . If not comment.then I will update the answer

Comment: Yes I did it.  All this would be impossible without your help and I really thank you so much.

Comment: Good you have modified answer yourself. but close this answer as accepted as described  [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)